# Android: How to customize facebook permission dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to work with FacebookSDK for android. I worked with the code of SessionLoginSample of Facebook. I'm trying to change the permission dialog so instead to look like this:

[image]

it will be look like this:

[image]

any ideas of what is the easiest way to implement this change in the SessionLoginSample example?

Comment: Why do you want this? This is intentionally not an option.

Comment: It looks more professional and nice. As I saw the most common apps use log-in dialogs like the second picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having the same issue I've learned this is the current look facebook uses to ask for permissions. I think that if you will ask for more advanced permissions it will lead you to a screen looking like the one you posted.